# LinkedIn API request with Python returns "Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields"

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I am trying to [Retrieve Statistics for Specific UGC Posts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics?tabs=http#retrieve-statistics-for-specific-ugc-posts) using the official documentations

My request looks like this:

```
requests.get(f'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A00000&ugcPosts[0]=urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A111111&ugcPosts[1]=urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A222222', headers = headers)
```

"00000" is the company ID

"111111" and "222222" - are ugcPosts URNs

The headers look like this:

```
def headers(access_token):
    '''
    Make the headers to attach to the API call.
    '''
    headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
    }
```

I have also passed the scope as one of the parameters, when authorizing:

```
def authorize(api_url,client_id,client_secret,redirect_uri):
    # Request authentication URL
    csrf_token = create_CSRF_token()
    params = {
        'response_type': 'code',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
        'state': csrf_token,
        'scope': 'r_liteprofile,r_emailaddress,w_member_social,r_organization_social,r_1st_connections_size,r_ads_reporting,rw_organization_admin,r_basicprofile,r_ads,rw_ads,w_organization_social'
        }
 
    response = requests.get(f'{api_url}/authorization',params=params)
```

Unfortunately this particular request doesn't give me the response I was expecting:

```
{'serviceErrorCode': 100, 'message': 'Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/ugcPosts[1], /ugcPosts[0]]', 'status': 403}
```

It works ok, when requesting a list of all ugcPosts

```
requests.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A00000)&sortBy=CREATED&count=100', headers = headers)
```

I have no clue what am I don't wrong. Can you please help me with my predicament?

The full request code is here

```
import requests
import json
 
from liapiauth import auth, headers

def organization_info(headers):
    response = requests.get(f'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A00000&ugcPosts[0]=urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A1111111&ugcPosts[1]=urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A2222222', headers = headers)
    organization_info = response.json()
    return organization_info
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    credentials = 'credentials.json'
    access_token = auth(credentials)
    headers = headers(access_token)
    organization_info = organization_info(headers)

with open('lisharelist.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(organization_info, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, that the problem is in request formatting. The documentation is outdated.
The sample request looks like this:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:2414183&ugcPosts[0]=urn:li:ugcPost:1000000&ugcPosts[1]=urn:li:ugcPost:1000001
```

Apart from changing ":" to "%3A" we also have to edit the list of ugcPosts. Here is the correct looking sample request:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A2414183&ugcPosts=List(urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A1000000,urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A1000001)
```